# How do I access my Google Assistant notes from my computer?

Tags: google-assistant, notes

I made a bunch of hands free voice notes while I was driving and now I need to process them from my computer, which has my to do list on it (which I cannot access from my phone).  However, I cannot seem to figure out how to do this.  When I ask Google Assistant where my notes are, it shows me a long list and says they are stored in Google Keep.  However, I do not see them in Keep.

As a workaround, I tried copying my notes on my phone, but it would not let me select more than one at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link worked for me for lists and notes I took before I had a synchronization account set up:

https://assistant.google.com/lists/mainview

Comment: Wow, I looked there and under notes there are a bunch of notes.  I haven't looked at it for a while as I had kind of given up, but I think these must be them.

Answer (score 1):

When you first make a note, Google Assistant normally asks you if you want them saved in Keep or Gmail...

If you selected Gmail, open https://mail.google.com on your PC and look for the Notes section on the left column.

If you selected Keep, go to https://keep.google.com and they should be there.

Comment: Yeah, except... it doesn't do that any more.  Unless I am in airplane mode.

Comment: @Michael I am confused... if you phone is in Airplane Mode, how are the documents available on Gmail/Keep to your PC? I don't really understand your comment. It might be worthwhile to check what app GA is using by default for your notes: https://www.guidingtech.com/change-note-app-google-assistant/

Comment: What I mean is, if I am *not* in airplane mode, it gets put in some place that is not keep that I can't seem to access from my PC.  If I am in airplane mode, it goes into Keep, and after I exit airplane mode it gets synced.

Comment: @Michael So what you're really asking is where/how they are stored on the device locally, and if you can access that? Not exact what your original question was, but that seems to be a million dollar question as they are not accessible according to the searching I have done.